# A function with positive $n$-th derivative has at most $n$ real roots – is there an extension into the complex domain?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives, roots

> Is there some meaningful extension of the following result into complex domain? [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617106/a-function-with-positive-n-th-derivative-has-at-most-n-roots-an-inequality)
>
> > Let $n\in \mathbb N$, and let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that its $n$-th derivative $f^{(n)}(x)>0, \ \forall x\in \mathbb R$, then $f$ has at most $n$ roots.

**Context:** The fundamental theorem of algebra can be interpreted that:

> If a function $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ (that is not identical to $0$) has a constant $n$-th derivative, then it has at most $n$ roots in $\mathbb C$.

Restricting attention to the real line only, it implies that $f$ has at most $n$ real roots, which, as shown in [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617106/a-function-with-positive-n-th-derivative-has-at-most-n-roots-an-inequality), holds under a somewhat weaker assumption that the $n$-th derivative of $f$ is strictly positive (and not necessarily constant).

**Note:** Assume that $f(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R$. Then the assumption that $f^{(n)}(x)>0$ is indeed weaker than the assumption that $f^{(n)}$ is constant (and not 0). It is so because if $f^{(n)}(x)<0$, then we could apply the result to $-f$ instead.

**Question:** *What restrictions need to be imposed on $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ besides that $f^{(n)}(x)>0$ on the real line in order to guarantee that $f$ has at most $n$ roots in $\mathbb C$?*

**Note:** Since considering multiplicity of a root of a function that is not a polynomial is problematic, I don't expect to be able to be able to formulate the result as that there is exactly $n$ roots in $\mathbb C$ considering their multiplicity.

Comment: as opposed to the real case when for example $1/(1+x^2)$ is a real analytic and hence infinitely differentiable with no zeroes but tricky to classify, entire functions with at most $n$ zeroes are of the form $f(z)=P(z)e^{g(z)}, \deg P \le n$ and in particular if $f$ is of finite order it then is of integer order $k$ so of the form $P(z)e^{Q(z)}$ where $\deg Q = k$ but other than that not sure what else can be said

Comment: @MartinR This would be indeed a very nice characterization.

Comment: @MartinR I meant the later case: “nonzero $n$-th derivative” (constant is the assumption in FTA which I want to relax).

Comment: @PavelKocourek:  Now you write: “If a function ... has a **constant** $n$-th derivative” – do you mean “**nonzero** $n$-th derivative”?

Comment: @MartinR Let me clarify that the statement in the ">" block at the beginning of the "Context" paragraph is nothing but restatement of the FTA (since constant $n$-th derivative is equivalent to $f$ being a polynomial of degree at most $n$). As late as in the paragraph below that I discuss the way this statement could be generalizes by replacing the assumption that $f^{(n)(x)}$ is constant by the assumption that it is nonzero (which by https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4617420/1134951 is equivalent to always positive / negative). Does it make sense like this or did I miss something?

Comment: I will appreciate any suggestions on how to prevent the question being confusing.

Comment: @PavelKocourek: I was referring to your sentence *“If a function $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ (that is not identical to $0$) has a **constant** $n$-th derivative, then it has at most $n$ roots in $\mathbb C$”*  – If the n-th derivative is constant then $f$ is a polynomial, that is not the interesting case.

Comment: @MartinR Exactly, that is why I refer to it as an interpretation of FTA. I wanted to emphasize the fact that polynomials can be seen as functions with constant $n$-th derivative, to make the parallel between the claim (assuming that $F^{(n)}(x)>0$) and FTA more apparent.

Comment: @PavelKocourek: OK, I See now what you mean. But note that *“$f^{(n)}(x)>0$ on the real line”* makes no sense in general for complex-valued functions.

Comment: @MartinR Good point. I just edited the question and clarified that the assumption $f^{(n)}(x)>0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb R$ is weaker than the assumption that $f^{(n)}(x)$ provided by that $f(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142028/discussion-between-martin-r-and-pavel-kocourek).

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there is an analogue statement for holomorphic functions in the complex plane (i.e. for “entire” functions).

The function $f(z) = z^{n-1} + e^z$ has the $n$-th derivative $f^{(n)}(z) = e^z$ which is nonzero everywhere. But $f$ has infinitely many zeros, see for example [$e^z-P(z)$ has infinitely many zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1782941/42969).

Comment: Thank you for this observation! Yet, this does not satisfy the assumption $Re(f^{(n)}(z))>0$ that you mentioned in the comments. So there is still hope that the assumption $Re(f^{(n)}(z))>0$ might be sufficient.

Comment: @PavelKocourek: I deleted that comment because it is useless for entire functions. If $Re(f^{(n)}(z))>0$ for all $z$ then $f^{(n)}$ is necessarily constant.

Answer (score 1):

If a holomorphic function, say $f(z)$, has at most $n$ roots, say $z_1,...,z_n$ then
$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_1)..(z-z_n)}$ has not roots. So it can be lifted, i.e. $g(z) = e^{h(z)}$ for some holomorphic $h(z)$. In words, a holomorphic function with at most $n$ roots has to have form $f(z) = p(z)e^{h(z)}$ where $p$ is a polynomial of degree not bigger than $n$.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this observation! I'm still wondering however, if there is a way to characterize the fact that $f$ can be represented in the form $f(z)=p(z) e^{h(z)}$ by referring the the $n$-th derivative of $f$.