# Does nonzero derivative imply always positive / negative derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, roots, monotone-functions

Does the following claim hold?

> Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Then $f'(x)>0 \, \forall x\in \mathbb R$ or $f'<0\, \forall x\in \mathbb R$.

Note that $f$ is **not assumed to be continuously differentiable**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The claim is true.* (And perhaps trivial for anyone who remembers the Darboux's theorem, which I must admit I learned only recently.)

**Proof.** For contradiction, suppose that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ does not have a zero derivative anywhere, but there are points $a,b\in \mathbb R$ such that $f'(a)<0<f'(b)$. Applying the [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) it follows that there exists $x\in [a,b]$ such that $f'(x)=0$. Contradiction. $\tag*{$\Box$}$

Comment: *I learned only recently* --- You might be interested in the MSE question [How irregular can $f'$ be beyond Darboux's Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2570732/13130) Also the 3rd paragraph of my [21 May 2008 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/Pk_pWyP-8Pc/m/YcnSAIVzTbwJ), altered only by changing ASCII math symbols to LaTeX math symbols (for the references I've cited, see the original sci.math post and [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1947-53-02/S0002-9904-1947-08757-7/) for Clarkson's 1947 paper): Derivatives also satisfy **(continued)**

Comment: stronger versions of the intermediate value property. For example, $f'$ having the intermediate value property implies that the set $E(a,b) = \{x \in J: \; a < f'(x) < b \}$ is either empty or has cardinality of the continuum. Denjoy (1916) (later rediscovered by J. A. Clarkson in 1947) improved this by showing that each of the sets $E(a,b)$ is either empty or has positive measure. A further strengthening of the IVP for derivatives, stronger than this positive measure result, was made by Zygmunt Zahorski [3]. **(continued)**

Comment: Then Clifford E. Weil [4] came up with a property satisfied by all derivatives that is strictly stronger than Zahorski's property and, after this, Peter S. Bullen and D. N. Sarkhel [5] came up with a property satisfied by all derivatives that is strictly stronger than Weil's property. (This last paper might not the strongest result so far published, by the way.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for supplying the historical context and list of possible extensions.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose this function is not continuously differentiable. If $f$ is continuously differentiable then all is well and the result follows without difficulty.

Suppose that were not the case, $f'$ is discontinuous. We know that there can be no "simple" discontinuities of $f'$, one where both left hand and right hand limits of $f'$ exist but do not satisfy the criteria for continuity. A proof can be found, for example, in Rudin.

Since it is not possible for $f'$ to intersect the x-axis or "jump" across it, it should either be strictly positive or strictly negative.

Comment: A derivative has no simple discontinuities because it has the intermediate value property, and that is because of Darboux's theorem.