# Show that the number of zeros of $e^{2z}-P(z)$ is not finite

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $P(z) \neq 0$ be a complex polynomial. Use Jensen's Formula to show that the set of zeros of $e^{2z}-P(z)$ is not finite.

**ATTEMPT**

Suppose that it were finite, say the zeros are $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$, and they are inside of $D(0,R)$. Then, by Jensen's Formula,

\begin{align*}
\log |f(0)|=-\sum_{k=1}^n \log \left(\frac{R}{\left|a_k\right|}\right)+\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \log \left|f\left(R e^{i \theta}\right)\right| d \theta,
\end{align*}

where $f(z)= e^{2z}-P(z)$.

Now my idea was to show that $\int_0^{2 \pi} \log \left|f\left(R e^{i \theta}\right)\right| d \theta$ is divergent, and therefore the formula wasn't valid, I'm not sure how to compute $\log \left|e^{Re^{i\theta}} -P(Re^{i\theta})\right|$. I'm also aware of the following inequality derived from Jensen's Formula:

\begin{align*}
n(R)\leq CR^{\rho},
\end{align*}

where $\rho$ is the order of growth and $n(R)$ is the number of zeros inside $D(0,R)$, but it doesn't seem relevant here since it's a $\leq$-type inequality.

Comment: Here are two other proofs (not based on Jensen's formula): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1782941/42969

Comment: I am aware of those proofs, but I haven't seen Hadamard's Theorem in class, and since the question specifically asks to use Jensen's Formula, I'd like to see a solution using it.

Comment: @ImHackingXD Is there any reason for not accepting my answer?